# How to write plural form of M.S.?

Tags: plural-forms, abbreviations

If someone has two master of science degrees in math and computer science, when writing the degrees in abbreviation as "M.S. in math and in CS", how can we write its plural form, "M.S.' in math and in CS", or "M.S.'s in math and in CS"? Thanks.

Comment: Would you not list the university & year of the degree at the same time?  MS Math, U. of Somewhere, 2009; MS CS, U. of Elsewhere, 2006.

Comment: they were awarded at the same time from same university.

Comment: "M.S.s"?  Doesn't really look right does it?  I mean, how would you say it? "Em Es esses"?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most readable way to say this is more or less as you have it:

> He has two M.S. degrees, one in Math and one in Computer Science (both from the same university)

In some cases the degrees are awarded as part of a joint program, and you can say something like:

> He has a *dual* M.S. in Math and Computer Science

But this suggests it's **one** cross-disciplinary degree, and not two separate degrees.